# Optaplanner school timetable multiple student groups at the same room at same time

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to figure out how to allow multiple student groups(some configured number) to attend lesson on the same subject in the same room, at the same time.

I think I should use group by, but can't understand how to count those and penalize if greater than defined number.

Answer (score 1):

```
return forEach(Lesson.class)
.groupBy(Lesson::getTimeslot, Lesson::getRoom, sum(Lesson::getStudentCount)
.filter((timeslot, room, studentTotal) -> studentTotal > room.capacity)
.penalize("room capacity", ONE_HARD,
        (timeslot, room, studentTotal) -> studentTotal - room.capacity);
```

Comment: "Look, mom! No explanation sentences in my answer, only code." - "Didn't I raise you better than that, son?" - "Apparently not."

Comment: Thanks :D For now I had in mind more simple condition, I just wanted to count all student groups in a timeslot and penalize if greater than some number(without room capacity). Does the ConstraintCollector always ends up to base class - Lesson, meaning that I need to form my condition always in relation to that not something like this I described here?

Comment: Something like `forEach(Lesson.class).groupBy(Lesson::getTimeslot, sum(Lesson::getStudentCount).filter((timeslot,  studentTotal) -> studentTotal > someNumber)`?

Comment: No like literaly no more than 4 student groups can be at the same room at a time. Offcourse all of this you suggested would work, but this is my colledge project and I am trying to understand how these constraint work, since I will need to add more coplex ones later. :)

Comment: I think I figured it out. :D I did something like this: `.forEach(Lesson.class).groupBy(Lesson::getTimeslot, Lesson::getClassroom, toList()).filter(((timeslot, classroom, lessons) -> {
                    var studentGroups = lessons.stream().map(Lesson::getStudentGroup).collect(Collectors.toSet());

                    return studentGroups.size() <= roomCapacity;
                }))
                .penalize("Room capacity exceeded", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);` Is this ok?